# Want to print comma separated values from array element

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want the user-id by comma separated. currently i  am getting output: Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
but i want as: 2,1

```
while($sel_2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
$t = $sel_2['userid'];
$string = explode(',',$t);
print_r($string);
}
```

Comment: You want implode `$string .= implode(',',$t);`

Comment: push id inside a container (array) implode after iteration

Comment: the userid will be so on, like: 2,1,3,2,1,4......so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do this:

```
$t = array();
while($sel_2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
   $t[] = $sel_2['userid'];
}
$string = implode(',',$t);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode.

```
while($sel_2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
$t[] = $sel_2['userid'];
}
$string = implode(',',$t);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = array()
while($sel_2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
    tmp[] = $sel_2['userid'];
echo implode(",", $tmp)
```